# divの高さを揃えたい

Tags: css, html

cssの`table`と`table-cell`を使ってdivを横に並べ、さらに入れ子にしたdivの高さを揃えたいです。下のsnippetで、赤い枠線の高さを左側と右側で同じにしたい。
左側の高さは内側の要素によって変わるので、`height`を明示的に指定することはできません。
JavaScriptを使用せずにcssのみで可能でしょうか？

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.table > div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.table > div > div {
  height: 100%;  /* 指定しても効果なし */
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>左側</p>
            <p>左側</p>
            <p>左側</p>
         </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <p>右側</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSSを以下のように変更することで対応できます。

- `.table`に`table-layout: fixed`を指定し、さらに`height`を指定
- `.table > div`に`height: 100%`を指定

参考サイト: [[CSS]要素を横並びに配置できる display:table-cell の基本的な使い方と注意点](http://www.webantena.net/css/display-table-cell/)

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.table > div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.table > div > div {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px; /* IE11, Firefox35ではこのpaddingによってはみ出る */
  border: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>左側</p>
            <p>左側</p>
            <p>左側</p>
         </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <p>右側</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。`.table`に指定する`height`は`1px`などの適当な値で良いということですね。
回答頂いたcssのコメントにあるように、IE、Firefoxでは線がはみ出てしまいますが、Chromeでは問題ありませんでした。cssの仕様としてはChromeの描画結果が正しいのでしょうか？